# use a SATA to USB cable with MacBook Pro optical drive?

Tags: usb, macbook, sata, optical-drive

Is there something fundamentally different about hard drives and optical drives regarding how they communicate with the computer? I ordered a [SATA to USB adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=5189) from Monoprice and I want to know whether it will work with an SATA optical drive removed from a MacBook Pro.

Can anyone shed some light on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

SATA is SATA. There's nothing that should stop you from it as long as it's actually SATA and not mSATA.

Comment: +1, SATA defines a physical connection and the logical link circuitry. It does not define the data protocol (which is still just plain old ATA for disk drives and ATAPI for CD type drives).